# Force Apache to Ignore a Request Using mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

We have certain IPs that, due to some load balancers and proxies, are tucked away in the X-Forwarded-For header and I have to block them with Apache using mod_rewrite (I know, we're getting a better solution together.) Currently, I'm just sending a 403 but I'd like to just have the request ignored altogether. How can I do this with mod_rewrite? Here's the directives I have now.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-For} ^111.111.111.111.*
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Comment: Maybe better off doing this with the firewall?  Or simply rewrite to a blank page.  I don't think you can halt or ignore a request through mod_rewrite.

Comment: @Rob He is already doing it with that rule. @Mark Firewall will be the best option. Next -- maybe deny access rule (`deny 111.111.111.111`), but it will still produce the log entry + similar 403 response will be sent back.

Comment: Yeah the firewall is the ideal option but one I don't have at the moment (this is for work so these aren't by my choice.) I was thinking of mod_rewrite only because it can do rules based on HTTP headers. But I've been reading the documentation and can't find anything like what I want to do. Now it's sounding like Apache itself doesn't have a mechanism for this. I suppose their reason is because it's probably outside of some RFC. I may just have to tell the jefes that Apache can't do what they want. Thanks for the help though.